# How to avoid using get(0) in list iteration

Tags: java, list, data-structures, iterator, iteration

Is there any way by which I can avoid using `get(0)` in the list iteration ?

Its going to be always risky using `get(0)` while iterating over a list.

I know for sure that in this list I just have one object.

(P.S. I remember my last manager always saying to me to avoid using `get(0)` on list iteration.)

Comment: Q: Any idea *why* this manager told you to "avoid using get(0)"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "risky" but you might consider using Guava's [`Iterables.getOnlyElement`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getOnlyElement-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
List<String> foo = getListFromSomewhere();
String bar = Iterables.getOnlyElement(foo);
```

This makes it clear that you expect there to be one and only one element. If you think there may be no elements, you can use the overload which allows you to specify a default value.

That way your expectations are checked when you ask for the element... but it's not obvious what else you're looking for. (You remember your last manager warning you about this - but do you remember *why* he warned you?)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I misuderstood the question, not realizing there was only a single item in the List. While my options still work, they aren't really necessary.  However, I question the danger of using `get(0)` if your precondition is that there is a list with a single element.

You have a few options:

First is simply let the loop get the object for you with a for-each loop

```
 for(Object thing : things)
```

Second, is convert the list into another form and access it in the appropriate manner:

```
Object[] thingArray = things.toArray();
for(int i = 0; i < thingArray.length; i++)
```

Third is to use the [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

```
ListIterator<Object> thingIterator = things.listIterator();
while(thingIterator.hasNext())
{
    Object thing = thingIterator.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object objOne = list.iterator().next();
```